# How to specify custom paths for ec2.py and ec2.ini?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-inventory

Till now, I had my `ec2.py` and `ec2.ini` files in the directory: `/etc/ansible/inventory`.

However, now as I need to run my playbook inside AWS Lambda, I need to have all the files in the root folder, which means both of those files should be in the same path as the playbook's `.yml` file.

So, how do I make it work?

Do I need to make changes the `ansible.cfg` file, or make changes in the Ansible run command, which currently is: `ansible-playbook -vvv demo_provision.yml -b -e "N= bucket_name=bucket_name"` ?

My `ansible.cfg` file is currently:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o ForwardAgent=yes
retries=2
sk_sudo_pass = yes

[defaults]
remote_user = root
host_key_checking = False
inventory = /etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply the inventory on the command line. If everything has to be on the same level, just copy everything there and say:

```
ansible-playbook -i ec2.py -vvv demo_provision.yml -b -e "N= bucket_name=bucket_name"
```

By default the `ec2.py` will search for the `ec2.ini` file in the same directory as your inventory, so if that's in the root that's fine as well.

You can also remove the `inventory = /etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.py` file from your config if you are always using the inventory provided on the command line as well